# Import 3d Mesh Godot Engine

Tags: godot

I am trying to load a model inside the Godot engine using only code. This is what my project looks like:

[image]

I create the camera without problems but I can't see my 3D model...

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get any errors on runtime? What are the import settings of your glb? Usually a glb is imported as an scene, not as a mesh. If it is, then trying to set it as a mesh should fail, and I would expect some error message.

Comment: No, I don't have any errors. But then how do I load a glb model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A glb file would usually※ be imported as a scene, not as a mesh. That is because a glb file can have multiple meshes, materials, skeleton data, animations, and even cameras and lights but these last two are unusual in practice.

※: You could have told Godot to not import the glb at all, or have defined a custom resource importer for it.

Thus, assuming everything is going well, the expression `load("Graficos/cubo.glb")` should be giving you a `PackedScene`. Let us start with that:

```
var glb_scene:PackedScene = load("Graficos/cubo.glb")
```

Now, to get an instance of `PackedScene` you call the instance method on it. Which will return a `Node`. In the case of a glb we expect said node to be an `Spatial`. We can do that:

```
var glb_scene:PackedScene = load("Graficos/cubo.glb")
var glb_model:Spatial = glb_scene.instance()
```

And now that you have a `Node` you can add it to your scene:

```
var glb_scene:PackedScene = load("Graficos/cubo.glb")
var glb_model:Spatial = glb_scene.instance()
add_child(glb_model)
```

And manipulate it:

```
var glb_scene:PackedScene = load("Graficos/cubo.glb")
var glb_model:Spatial = glb_scene.instance()
add_child(glb_model)
glb_model.translate(Vector3(0.0, 0.0, -10.0))
```