# Godot AnimTree Not Found

Tags: godot

I use this function to play one of my model's animations

```
modelo.get_node("AnimationPlayer").play("Anim1")
```

But it doesn't work if I want to play another animation of the model at the same time. I have read about AnimationTree, but if i do this:

```
modelo.get_node("AnimationTree").play("Anim2")
```

I get an error message. **get_node: Node not found: AnimationTree**

My question is, how is AnimationTree used?

Comment: At the risk of stating the painfully obvious, do you have a node called `AnimationTree` on the current scene?

Comment: No, I don't have an AnimationPlayer node either, but the first one does work

Comment: `get_node` only returns nodes which exist in your scene tree as direct children of the node you're calling it on. What is `modelo` and what are its direct children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going on limb and guess - given [your prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75805675/402022) and this one - that you have imported and loaded a gltf or glb in your `modelo` variable.

As I said in the prior answer you get an `Spatial`, but that is not the whole story.

If the model has animations, that `Spatial` will have a child `AnimationPlayer`. Also, presumably it will have some other `Spatial` and `MeshInstance`. And if it is rigged, you should find an `Skeleton` too. *It might have other things, but these are the usual.*

The *usual* structure is something like this:

```
Spatial
├ Spatial
│ └ Spatial
│   └ Skeleton
│     ├ MeshInstance
│     ├ MeshInstance
│     └ MeshInstance
└ AnimationPlayer
```

Yes, the `AnimationPlayer` will be in that position if there are animations. The `Skeleton` will be some number of `Spatial`s deep. And the names of said `Spatial`s, and also the names of the `MeshInstance`s, will vary.

So, when you do this:

```
modelo.get_node("AnimationPlayer")
```

You are getting that `AnimationPlayer`.

---

As you have found out, there isn't an `AnimationTree`. You would have to add an `AnimationTree` node to your scene. You also need to tell the `AnimationTree` which `AnimationPlayer` it will use, and enable it.

From code that would be like this:

```
animation_tree.anim_player = animation_player.get_path()
animation_tree.active = true
```

Please note that you need to get the references to the `AnimationTree` and `AnimationPlayer` first. For example, in your code you are getting a reference to the `AnimationPlayer` with `get_node`.

Also be aware that for the `AnimationTree` Godot has panel that appears on the bottom of the editor, which you would use to configure it. See the article [Using AnimationTree](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/animation/animation_tree.html). You might also be interested in [Controlling Animation States](https://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/3.x/animation/animation_state_machine/).

To answer the question "how is AnimationTree used?", you usually setup an state machine, and then tell it to *travel* to a particular animation in said state machine.

Yes, it is possible to configure the `AnimationTree`, create said state machine and so on, entirely from code, although it is not ideal.